# What‘s the best way to paint a flat on your own?

Tags: painting, spraypainting

I am moving to a new flat soon and I want to paint the flat.
I am wondering what would be the best approach to paint the flat if I want to do it myself. The flat is 90m2. I want to paint the walls and ceiling.

Should I use a paint roller / brushes or is it worth it to use a paint sprayer if I have never used one before?
The end result doesn‘t need to be perfect, just decent / „good enough“.

How many layers should I paint? If multiple layers, how long do I need to wait between layers?
Currently, the walls mostly have a light ivory colour, except for some patches of white, where the previous tenant patched things up. I want to paint everything white.

Comment: IIRC "flat" is Commonwealth-speak for "apartment," which on this side of the pond is a rented home.  Here, you generally need a landlord's approval if you want to paint a rental.  Is this a rental, and do such customs apply where you live?

Comment: @Huesmann in the UK, flats are often (but of course not always)  owner-occupied.  If rented, then yes, you'd need approval.

Comment: New to you or brand new? What finish do the walls have already?  The top voted answer seems to assume bare walls as it calls for primer, which isn't an assumption I'd make

Comment: Please see the [help] and take the [tour]. You're asking multiple questions here, some of which are highly subjective.

Answer (score 5):

If you have no experience, the best way to paint an entire flat quickly for a move-in is to hire a professional.

If you want to learn and do it yourself, do not set yourself this challenge.
**Start with one room.**  Move in to the rest of the flat and leave one room empty for learning to paint.

Expect to spend a a full week, or a month of weekends, learning but ending up with a great result.  You'll watch a lot of youtube tutorials, you'll talk to the guy at the paint store, you'll try different brushes and rollers, learn the techniques that work best for you.

Subsequent rooms will go a lot faster ... two days if you're not stripping old wood or dealing with old cracked plaster.

If you have *some* experience, whether with brushes, rollers, sprayers .... go with what you have.  Again, learning new techniques and tools while trying to rapidly prepare an entire home for move-in is not a good mix.

As for the number of coats, it depends on the quality of paint and the condition of the walls.  From your description ... the walls are light colored already, they are entirely painted already, and you're painting them a light color.  Don't buy the cheapest paint and don't buy expensive "one coat" paint.  Buy average paint and you'll need two coats.

Answer (score 5):

Use brush and roller. I paint mostly with a professional airless sprayer, and the cons/pros of roller vs. sprayers are  a close call even for me. Spraying requires an enormous amount of prep, it uses a lot more paint, requires a lot of cleanup afterwards, the right equipment is expensive, and is not forgiving of mistakes. I use it because I generally paint unoccupied houses and need to work quickly. Using a roller and brush allows you to pace yourself, correct mistakes as you go, and the prep/cleanup are relatively minor. And it's cheaper.

Having said that:

1. Buy the highest quality brushes and rollers you can find.
2. Buy separate primer and paint.
3. Buy good quality paint.

The rest is kinda obvious.